# Почему hamburger не работает на в media запросах?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
var headerList = document.querySelector('.header-list');

button.onclick = function() {
  headerList.classList.toggle('openMneu');
};
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #13334c;
}

.hamburger {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  top: 8px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hamburger .fa-bars {
  color: #fff;
}

.logo {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo__link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header-list__item {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 26px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

.header-list__item:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}

.header-list__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.openMneu {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 578px) .header-list display: none .hamburger z-index: 100 top: -70px visibility: visible
```

```html
<nav class='nav'>
  <ul class="header-list">
    <li class="header-list__item"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Услуги</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Примеры</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>О нас</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Контакты</li>
  </ul>
  <button class='hamburger'>
       <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
     </button>
</nav>
```

Comment: Может потому что Вы забыли скобки? :)

Comment: @meine  у меня sass так что ваш ответ мимо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, дело все же в фигурных скобках и в отсутствии точек с запятой?

Потому что ваш вариант на css работает.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
var headerList = document.querySelector('.header-list');

button.onclick = function() {
  headerList.classList.toggle('openMneu');
};
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #13334c;
}

.hamburger {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  top: 8px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hamburger .fa-bars {
  color: #fff;
}

.logo {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo__link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header-list__item {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 26px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

.header-list__item:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}

.header-list__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.openMneu {
  display: block !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 578px) {
  .header-list {
    display: none;
  }
  .hamburger {
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <nav class='nav'>
    <ul class="header-list">
      <li class="header-list__item"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
      <li class="header-list__item">
        <a href="#"></a>Услуги</li>
      <li class="header-list__item">
        <a href="#"></a>Примеры</li>
      <li class="header-list__item">
        <a href="#"></a>О нас</li>
      <li class="header-list__item">
        <a href="#"></a>Контакты</li>
    </ul>
    <button class='hamburger'>
       <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
              button
     </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, проблема была в том, стили перебивались вел !important и все заработало

Comment: @user332017 к важности того, почему надо в вопросе задавать конкретный вопрос. `@media only screen and (max-width: 578px) .header-list display: none .hamburger z-index: 100 top: -70px visibility: visible` Неужели вот это на `sass` работает? Именно так, записанное в одну строчку?

Comment: @Степан Касьяненко это называется когда пишешь на sass, берешь компилированный код из css и  его лень исправлять

Comment: @user332017 жаль, что я узнал это только сейчас. Знал бы, что вам лень, не стал бы отвечать ((